# El JDK 9 no es compatible con sistemas de 32 bits

Tags: java

He intentado instalar el JDK de Java 9 pero en la página oficial no encuentro la versión para sistemas de 32 bits, por lo que me gustaría saber si Java 9 es solo para 64 bits o más adelante será liberada la versión de 32 bits.

Comment: Hola. Esta respuesta puede servirte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356345/can-java-9-run-on-a-32-bit-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es:

<s>**Actualmente no**, y quizá sea así por mucho tiempo o definitivamente.</s>

**Java 9 definitivamente no soportará 32 bits**.

Desde el JDK 9 trabajará con un máquina virtural tipo servidor.

En el apartado ***[Removed tools and components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-59701F80-5BB1-416D-835D-C39A9112FC1E)*** podemos leer esto:

> ### Dropped Windows 32–bit Client VM
>
> In JDK 9, the Windows 32–bit client VM is not available. Only a server
> VM is offered.
>
> JDK 8 and earlier releases offered both a client JVM and a server JVM
> for Windows 32-bit systems. JDK 9 offers only the server JVM. The
> server JVM is tuned to maximize peak operating speed.

---

> #### El cliente de la VM de 32 bits abandonado
>
> En JDK 9, la máquina virtual (VM) cliente de Windows 32 bits no está
> disponible. Solo se ofrece una máquina virtual de servidor.
>
> JDK 8 y versiones anteriores ofrecían una JVM de cliente y una JVM de
> servidor para sistemas Windows de 32 bits. JDK 9 ofrece solo el
> servidor JVM. La JVM del servidor está preparada para maximizar la
> velocidad de la carga operativa máxima.

Mark Reinhold, el  jefe de arquitectura de la plataforma fue consultado al respecto y ésta fue [su respuesta](https://twitter.com/mreinhold/status/912311207935090689) vía Twitter el 25 de septiembre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Traducido:

> Lo sentimos, pero no tenemos planes de enviar compilaciones de JDK 9
> de 32 bits. Estamos intentando centrarnos más en el futuro que en el
> pasado.

Al parecer en un principio la página [Oracle JDK 9 and JRE 9 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk9certconfig-3761018.html) incluía los sistemas de 32 bits, pero esa información desapareció, y ahora sólo hay referencia a sistemas de 64 bits.

Tu misma pregunta fue planteada en el [blog de Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4083972) y también en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356345/can-java-9-run-on-a-32-bit-os), se sugiere crear sus propios binarios en versión 32 bits y en el último enlace parece ofrecerse algunos. Usar binarios de terceros tiene su riesgo, claro está. Quizá la mejor opción sea, si es posible, *mirar hacia el futuro*, como dice Reinhold,  y pasar a un sistema de 64 bits.